# MLG PRO DC Final video

Tags: starcraft-2

MLG PRO DC finished for some hours ago and I want to watch the finals between HuK and Idra.

Is there any way to watch this without paying the MLG page? Can it be found on the internet on for example YouTube?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MLG is pretty good about posting replays.  Right now they're not up but when they are you can find them [here](http://www.mlgpro.com/ci/brackets/procircuit/10/dc/sc2/open).

For Idra vs Huk you should be able to see them [here](http://media.mlgpro.com/brackets/10/procircuit/dc/sc2/open/matches/4085.html)

Comment: Im getting not found when clicking the replays

Comment: @Anders As I mentioned, `Right now they're not up`.  Usually there is lag time between a large event and the posting of replays.

Comment: They're up now.

Comment: Yeah i have been watching them. Any way to find the once where day9 is commentating?